# Not able open a webapp using IP in another machine?

Tags: linux, web-applications, playframework-2.0, firewall

I am running a Play-based webapp on a Linux machine: 
[image]

and on this machine I can see it working: 
[image]

I need to open the webapp on another machine. So I got the ip: 
[image]

The webapp opens using the ip on the original machine: 
[image]

But I am not able to open it on other machine: 
[image]

What can be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is a wrong port. The standard HTTP port is 80. Only this port is relayed in the internet for this protocol (HTTP). You are using port 8010 which works fine on your local machine and maybe even your local network (depends on the switch/router settings) but it will fail if you try to connect to this server from the internet. Just exchange the port in `-Dhttp.port` parameter from 8010 to 80 when you start your play app.